# jQuery recognising incorrect state of radio buttons on page load when radio value="No" and neither radio is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have radio buttons on a page which add or remove a css class from other elements according to their state.

The class `testclass` is added to the element `slave` by default (i.e. the HTML the page loads is:

```
<input type="radio" value="No" name="master" /> No
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="master" /> Yes

<input type="text" name="a" id="slave" class="testclass" />
```

The following jQuery removes the class if the "No" radio is selected

```
$("input[name$='master']").change(function(){
    if(this.value === 'No') {
          $('#slave').removeClass('testclass'); 
    } else {
         $('#slave').addClass('testclass');
    }
}); $("input[name$='master']").filter(':checked').change()
```

This works fine in terms of moving back and forward between the states once the page has loaded, but I am triggering the function on page load and it **removes** the class at that time, when no check radio is selected. (It's fine if "Yes" is loaded as checked).

**Interestingly it is also fine if I reverse the condition such that "Yes" is required to remove the class (page loads with class still there).**

I thought javascript might be equating no selection made with a value of "No" hence I tried the strict equality, but no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: $("input[name$='master']").change(function(){} will only work once you change the state of the radio button that has the name attribute that contains "master". So obviously the code in this function will not fire on pageload.

Comment: Why is the class being removed then?

Comment: Ya that looks strange. Apparently it should only come inside this function if the state of radio is changed. A better way to know what is happening is by introducing a breakpoint just above the line "if(this.value === 'No')". Now if you refresh your page and the code stops at the debugger, we would know that the function is being called at pageload.

Comment: Sure I can do that - sorry I should clarify something I realise I didn't put in my code, the function is inside a `$( document ).ready()`, so that's why it's calling at page load I think? That's necessary to get the state to be checked on page load isn't it?

Comment: Naa I think that is something normal. Kindly insert the breakpoint there for now. Let me make a fiddle for you out of this code so that you understand better. I will then post it as an answer.

Comment: Er, I think I set a breakpoint (not very experienced) installed firequery, put the red dot on the left of the script at the point you specified, reloaded the page... I think it broke because now there's a yellow triangle inside the red dot... and the page is inactive but present (I can't click and fields in page)... sorry, that's not a very technical resposne!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43188/discussion-between-gideon-and-talha-masood)

Comment: No problem @Gideon. At least you are trying to learn and that's great. Kindly see the answer I have posted. Will give you a better idea

Comment: Any difference you see between `Yes` and `No` are purely coincidental. JavaScript or HTML don't treat the string "No" in any special way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have developed a fiddle for you to consider. Here is the link to it => http://jsfiddle.net/6c7F2/

I think the best way to answer this question is to make you understand a few things about the code you have provided here. I am going to write in comments to it.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ // this function is called once your page loads
    $("input[name$='master']").change(function(){
        //this function is not called until you click the radio buttons. 
        // Be careful to note that this function is never called on page load. 
        // You can test it in the fiddle I created
        if(this.value === 'No') {
            $('#slave').removeClass('testclass'); 
            // this alert in the fiddle is called only
            // when you click the radio buttons. Not on page load
            alert("It entered");
        } else {
            $('#slave').addClass('testclass');
        }
    }); 
    $("input[name$='master']").filter(':checked').change()
});
```

So make sure that the things and checks you want to execute on page load should be outside the scope of `$("input[name$='master']").change(function(){});`

This is only triggered when you click on radio buttons and not on page load.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have not selected any value on page load and still you are triggering the event.

Try:

Select any checkbox by default.

```
<input type="radio" value="No" name="radios" checked="checked"/> No
```

OR

Remove this line

```
$("input[name$='master']").filter(':checked').change()
```

Comment: Hmm but I need the form to be blank before a user saves any data, and I also need to load page state when they arrive if there *is* a state to load. 

Also it works fine with the requirement being "Yes" and there being no state chosen. Any idea why "No" is different?